# How to add the variables of array to database table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form. Posting array variables from this form in the same name. (Sorry for my bad English.)
Here is the example:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control">
```

It is coming like ["a", "b", "c"]

I need save this variables to mysql from array. Not with array. Just one by one.

Create from my post controller

```
array_length = params[:type].size
for i in 0..array_lenth
  type = params[:type][i]
  name = params[:name][i]
  title = params[:title][i]
  value = params[:value][i]

  #And save code.
end
```

I know i can save with some normal sql query but i dont know should i use or how i can use params require permit . something like

```
def form_params
  params.require(:form).permit(:id, :type, :name, :value, :title, :post_id)
end
```

If i use this, how can i determine the necessary variables. Please help me and sorry for my English :)

Note: I have new post form and i have to add some variables to another table in post form (it is those arrays)

Comment: first of all, use form_params instead of params in the create controller. you dont need the for loop

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify that the param is an actual array, something like:

```
def form_params
  params.require(:form).permit(:id, :type, :value, :title, :post_id, name: [:name_of_attribute, :another_name_for_attribute])
end
```

And then for your form:

```
<div class="field">
 <%= form.text_field "name[name_for_attribute]" %>
</div>
```

Where the `name_for_attribute` is the name of the attribute you want it to be, so on the controller you will read the params like:

```
"form" => {"name"=>{"name_for_attribute"=>"The entered value"}
```

You can change the `name_for_attribute` for whatever you want and if for some reason someone tries to add another weird thing into the array by inspecting the HTML, you will filter all the attributes you want anyway.

Hope this helps! Let me know how it goes